# What did it once mean to "get up" a chapter of history?

Tags: idioms, nineteenth-century-english

In John Henry Newman's article (circa 1854) entitled [*Discipline of Mind*](http://www.newmanreader.org/works/idea/article9.html), he writes

> "what a lesson in memory and discrimination it is to get up, as it is
>   called, any one chapter of history"

What did the expression "get up" mean for Newman?  Was it to master a subject?  Or to memorize a document?  Or otherwise?

Comment: Did you find any other examples of this? Also did you look up any dictionaries for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get up** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/77994?redirectedFrom=to%20get%20up#eid3139005) transitive

> d. **To acquire a knowledge of (a subject)** for a special purpose or by a
>   special effort.

As in:

> 1866   T. Carlyle Inaug. Addr. Edinb. 172   There is a process called
>   cramming..that is, **getting-up** such points of things as the
>   Examiner is likely to put questions about.

and

> 2002   D. Emmott Clergy Training in Victorian York 9   It was not
>   enough simply to spend a little time **‘getting up’** the subjects for
>   the Bishop's examination.

to get up= to study, learn, peruse;

> study intensively, as before an exam  [vocab.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/get%20up)